# Acceder a ManyToMany Fields

Tags: python, django

Saludos tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Proveedor(models.Model):

    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.razon_social
```

en mi views.py estoy generando un reporte excel donde deseo mostrar las categorias de cada uno de los proveedores:

```
for proveedor in Proveedor.objects.all().filter(estado=1):
   ...
    ws.cell(row=cont, column=8).value = proveedor.categoria.all.join(", ")
```

Me genera el siguiente error:

> invalid syntax (views.py, line 381)

Es decir, esta mal la forma como deseo mostrar las categorías, quizá alguna sugerencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diego, el método `all` pertenece a `QuerySet`, por lo tanto no puedes aplicarle la función `join` que es usada para cadenas de texto.

Si lo que quieres es aplicarlo a los nombres de las categorías, podrías hacer algo así:

```
categorias = [c.nombre for c in proveedor.categoria.all()]
ws.cell(row=cont, column=8).value = ', '.join(categorias)
```

Es sencillo, lo que estás haciendo realmente es algo como esto:

```
>>> categorias = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> ', '.join(categorias)
'A, B, C, D'
```

Comment: Genial gran respuesta, solo una pregunta he visto que usas "[c.nombre for c in proveedor.categoria.all()]" y he visto esto en varios codigos como se llama esa forma de trabajar con el ciclo for.. gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola @DiegoAvila, eso se conoce como list-comprehensions o "listas por compresión" puedes mirarte la documentación oficial si lo deseas: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. La misma sintaxis se puede usar para crear diccionarios (`d = {k: v for k, v in [["a", 2], ["b", 3]]}`), conjuntos (`chars = {c for c in "hola mundo"}`) o generadores, llamadas en este caso expresiones generadoras (`g = (c for c in "hola mundo")`.

Comment: @FJSevilla muchas gracias por tu comentario..!!